# Give public privilege to login.html page with spring security

Tags: angularjs, spring-security

I integrated an AngularJs template ([SB Admin Angular](http://startangular.com/product/sb-admin-angular-theme/)) to a spring boot front-end application (the output of 'grunt built' command ).
i am trying to set the login.html page privileges to public. This is the code i used (not working)

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/index.html","/views/pages/login.html")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

Whenever i go to http://localhost:8080/#/login the browser's window shows up telling me that spring boot demands a username and a pass.
I need help to know what is the mistake i did.

this is my project structure

[image: project structure]

Again, if you ever wanted to explore the template and see how the ui-router is used in the template : http://startangular.com/product/sb-admin-angular-theme/

npm install then grunt build will create a dist directory that contains the template.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have login issue and so your cerdential are not get passed in to the application.
Use `formLogin`.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/index.html","/views/pages/login.html")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
                        HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response,
                        Authentication a) throws IOException, ServletException {
                            //To change body of generated methods,
                            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                        }
            })
            .failureHandler(new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationFailure(
                        HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response,
                        AuthenticationException ae) throws IOException, ServletException {
                            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                        }
            })
            .loginProcessingUrl("/access/login")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/access/logout")                
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new LogoutSuccessHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onLogoutSuccess(
                        HttpServletRequest request, 
                        HttpServletResponse response, 
                        Authentication a) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
                }
            })

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but this is not working.
in fact i just want to make login.html accessible to public, that is it.
I tried the same configuration class that i wrote (WebSecurityConfig) on another mini-template that contains index.html + state1.html + state2.html where index contains 2 links linking to state1 and state2.html and one view (ui-view). 
I tried to make state1.html accessible by public with the exact same code and it worked but it just doesn't with this template.

i just want the login.html to be public, that is all.

Comment: In my project the above code is working fine for login logout with proper credentials, but yes if you want public access then you should pass default `username` and `password` using inMemoryAuthentication
`.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("user")
    .password("password")
    .roles("USER");`